# Error during build for Android NDK on Windows with clang

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang, cross-compiling

Currently I am trying to deal with building a C shared library for Android. I have installed **Android Studio** with *NDK (Side by side)*, but have to build it all with another build tool (*Qbs* of an obsolete version, patched in numerous places of code). This is the thing I cannot avoid anyway.

So, I come up with the following task: having a **C language** object file, **my_api.c.o** (can be thought of as a static library), I need to build a shared library file, **libmyapi.so**, in *C language* as well. It is fairly just a blank **.c* file.

> The library usage is expected to be as follows: an Android application **myapplication.apk** (written in Java or Kotlin) references a JAR file **myapi.jar** (wrapper only), which contains a JNI shared library file **libjnimyapi.so** (Java runtime to native, stable interface), which uses the native shared library **libmyapi.so** (native runtime only, unstable implementation).

Now I am stuck with the following invocation of **clang**. Trying to build for *target Android x86-64* on *host Windows x86-64*, my build system calls (only replaced spaces with new lines):

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\\clang.exe
"-Wl,-soname=libmyapi.so,--as-needed,-m,elf_x86_64,-rpath,$ORIGIN,-z,noexecstack,-z,relro,-z,now"
-shared
"--sysroot=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot"
-LC:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android
-LC:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/26
-no-canonical-prefixes
-target
x86_64-none-linux-android
-o
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/libmyapi.so
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/ef09f097fcee0ffa/blank.c.o
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/my_api.c.o
-ldl
-lc
-lm
```

And it results in an error:

```
ERROR: ld.lld: error: cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
ld.lld: error: cannot open crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ERROR: Process failed with exit code 1.
```

Despite the needed files **are** there:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-android\26

27.11.2023  16:13    <DIR>          .
27.11.2023  16:13    <DIR>          ..
14.11.2023  10:24             3 104 crtbegin_dynamic.o
14.11.2023  10:24             3 288 crtbegin_so.o
14.11.2023  10:24             3 104 crtbegin_static.o
14.11.2023  10:24             1 024 crtend_android.o
14.11.2023  10:24               696 crtend_so.o
```

Executing *clang* solely (not from the build system) with `-v` option, I got:

```
"C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/ld.lld"
"--sysroot=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125\\/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot"
-z
now
-z
relro
--hash-style=both
--eh-frame-hdr
-m
elf_x86_64
-shared
-o
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/libmyapi.so
crtbegin_so.o
-LC:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android
-LC:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/26
-LC:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/x86_64
"-LC:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125\\/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android"
"-LC:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125\\/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib"
-soname=libmyapi.so
--as-needed
-m
elf_x86_64
-rpath
"\$ORIGIN"
-z
noexecstack
-z
relro
-z
now
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/ef09f097fcee0ffa/blank.c.o
D:/Repo/myapi/build/android-x86_64/debug/myapi-shared.53ad79c4/my_api.c.o
-ldl
-lc
-lm
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a
-l:libunwind.a
-ldl
-lc
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a
-l:libunwind.a
-ldl
crtend_so.o
```

This gave me some info, and I managed to google [this order](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#Unwinding), which seems to be fine anyway, and [this `-B` option](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1690#issuecomment-1529928723), which did not help and does not seem to be required...

Is there anything I am missing? Looks like **my_api.c.o** is compiled properly, but linking in into **libmyapi.so** fails. Is there any weird restriction in Android NDK, like that pure C (not C++) shared libraries cannot be built by the toolchain design? Does argument positioning (especially for `-L`) matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my build tool (Qbs of an obsolete version) could not handle the
`-target` option correctly. While it was using `x86_64-none-linux-android`, Android NDK API level was missing. Having this build tool's code corrected to add the missing number, I managed to make *clang* build with `x86_64-none-linux-android27`, and the library managed to get built.